# Limitar lo que muestra un ListView en android

Tags: java, android

Tengo una base de datos realm con 10 items, ¿cómo confecciono el adapter para que solo muestre algunos items el `ListView`? Por ejemplo, 3 o 4.

Tengo este adapter:

```
package bondi.developedsudaka.bondi.Adapters;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.List;

import bondi.developedsudaka.bondi.Models.Card;
import bondi.developedsudaka.bondi.R;


public class CardAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("E d MMM yyyy HH:mm a");

    private Context context;
    private List<Card>cards;
    private int layout;

    public CardAdapter(Context context, List<Card> cards, int layout) {
        this.context = context;
        this.cards = cards;
        this.layout = layout;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return cards.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return cards.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return cards.get(position).getId();
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        ViewHolder vh;
        if (convertView == null){
            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(layout, null);
            vh = new ViewHolder();
            vh.namecard = convertView.findViewById(R.id.nombrecard);
            vh.valorcard = convertView.findViewById(R.id.montocard);
            vh.fechatravel = convertView.findViewById(R.id.fecha_travel);
            vh.imgBackground = convertView.findViewById(R.id.colorcard);
            convertView.setTag(vh);
        }else{
            vh = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }
        Card card = cards.get(position);

        vh.namecard.setText(card.getNombrecard());
        vh.valorcard.setText(String.format("%.2f", card.getMontocard()));
        String createdAt = df.format(cards.get(position).getCreatedAt());
        vh.fechatravel.setText(createdAt);
        if (card.getImgBackground() == 0) {
            vh.imgBackground.setImageResource(R.drawable.button_1);
        } else if (card.getImgBackground() == 1) {
            vh.imgBackground.setImageResource(R.drawable.button_2);
        } else if (card.getImgBackground() == 2){
            vh.imgBackground.setImageResource(R.drawable.button_3);
        } else if (card.getImgBackground() == 3){
            vh.imgBackground.setImageResource(R.drawable.button_4);
        } else if (card.getImgBackground() ==4){
            vh.imgBackground.setImageResource(R.drawable.button_5);
        }else if(card.getImgBackground() ==5){
            vh.imgBackground.setImageResource(R.drawable.button_6);
        }else if (card.getImgBackground() == 6){
            vh.imgBackground.setImageResource(R.drawable.button_7);
        }else if (card.getImgBackground() == 7){
            vh.imgBackground.setImageResource(R.drawable.button_8);
        }else if (card.getImgBackground() == 8){
            vh.imgBackground.setImageResource(R.drawable.button_9);
        }else if (card.getImgBackground() == 9){
            vh.imgBackground.setImageResource(R.drawable.button_10);
        }else  if (card.getImgBackground() == 10){
            vh.imgBackground.setImageResource(R.drawable.button_11);
        }else if (card.getImgBackground() == 11){
            vh.imgBackground.setImageResource(R.drawable.button_12);
        }

        return convertView;
    }

    public class ViewHolder{
         TextView namecard;
         TextView valorcard;
         TextView fechatravel;
         ImageView imgBackground;
    }
}
```

Este es mi activity:

```
  package bondi.developedsudaka.bondi.UI;

import android.animation.Animator;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import bondi.developedsudaka.bondi.Adapters.BusAdapter;
import bondi.developedsudaka.bondi.Adapters.CardAdapter;
import bondi.developedsudaka.bondi.Adapters.TicketAdapter;
import bondi.developedsudaka.bondi.Models.Bus;
import bondi.developedsudaka.bondi.Models.Card;
import bondi.developedsudaka.bondi.Models.Ticket;
import bondi.developedsudaka.bondi.R;
import io.realm.Realm;
import io.realm.RealmChangeListener;
import io.realm.RealmResults;
import io.realm.Sort;

public class MyDashboard extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener,
        RealmChangeListener<RealmResults<Card>>{

    private Realm realm;

    private ListView cardlist;
    private CardAdapter cardAdapter;
    private RealmResults<Card>cards;
    private TextView textFecha, textTiempo;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_my_dashboard);

        final Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
        cards = realm.where(Card.class).sort("createdAt", Sort.DESCENDING).findAll();
        cards.addChangeListener(this);

        cardAdapter = new CardAdapter(this, cards, R.layout.template_card);
        cardlist = findViewById(R.id.cards_list);
        cardlist.setAdapter(cardAdapter);

}
    //region Region Metodo Recargar lista
    @Override
    public void onChange(RealmResults<Card> cards) {
        cardAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    }
    //endregion

}

Y este el listView:

    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
    tools:context="bondi.developedsudaka.bondi.UI.MyDashboard"
    tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_my_dashboard">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/m48dp">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/cards"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/t14sp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:textColor="?attr/colorPrimary"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/m16dp"/>

            </LinearLayout>

            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:cardElevation="@dimen/m10dp">

                <ListView
                    android:id="@+id/cards_list"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:scrollbars="vertical" />

            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Y este es el modelo:

```
    package bondi.developedsudaka.bondi.Models;

import android.graphics.drawable.ColorDrawable;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.support.annotation.ColorInt;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Date;

import bondi.developedsudaka.bondi.App.MyApplications;
import io.realm.RealmList;
import io.realm.RealmObject;
import io.realm.annotations.PrimaryKey;

/**
 * Created by ruben on 27/02/2018.
 */

public class Card extends RealmObject{

    @PrimaryKey
    private long id;
    private String nombrecard;
    private int imgBackground;
    private Double montocard;
    private Date createdAt;


    public Card() {
    }

    public Card(String nombrecard, int imgBackground, Double montocard) {
        this.id = MyApplications.CardID.incrementAndGet();
        this.nombrecard = nombrecard;
        this.imgBackground = imgBackground;
        this.montocard = montocard;
        this.createdAt = new Date();

    }

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getNombrecard() {
        return nombrecard;
    }

    public void setNombrecard(String nombrecard) {
        this.nombrecard = nombrecard;
    }

    public int getImgBackground() {
        return imgBackground;
    }

    public void setImgBackground(int imgBackground) {
        this.imgBackground = imgBackground;
    }

    public Double getMontocard() {
        return montocard;
    }

    public void setMontocard(Double montocard) {
        this.montocard = montocard;
    }

    public Date getCreatedAt() {
        return createdAt;
    }

    public void setCreatedAt(Date createdAt) {
        this.createdAt = createdAt;
    }
}
```

Comment: Para que se entienda mejor tu pregunta recuerda que debe de tener un [mcve]

Comment: Hola, Raul, lo ideal sería que enseñases un poco de código para ver que hiciste en el adapter, pero yo te recomiendo que le pases algún parámetro extra desde el modelo (si es que lo usas), por ejemplo si ahora le pasas 'nombre' y 'apellido' pasarle otro por ejemplo 'mostrar' y cuando se lo pases ponerle si quieres o no mostrarlo. Sin ver el código que tienes es difícil decir exactamente como hacerlo, pero espero que te puedas guiar un poco o poner el código.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Los items que se muestran se ven limitados por el metodo `getCount`. Asi que si quieres mostrar solo 3 o 4 elementos solo tienes que modificar esa funcion.

```
int numItemsDesplegar = 3;

@Override
public int getCount() {
     if(cards.size()<numItemsDesplegar){
          return cards.size;
     }
     return numItemsDesplegar;
     //return cards.size();
}
```

solo ten en cuenta que si el num de items en cards es menor que numItemsDesplegar, ocurriria un error, es por eso que agregue el if

Comment: Gracias por desasname amigo funciona espectacular